# Issue converting github.com/*/raw/* URLs to raw.githubusercontent.com URLS using AWK

Tags: awk, text-processing, unix-text-processing

Given the following example URLs:

**urls.txt**

```
https://github.com/2RDLive/Pi-Hole/raw/master/Blacklist.txt
https://github.com/34730/asd/raw/master/adaway-export
https://github.com/568475513/secret_domain/raw/master/filter.txt
https://github.com/BlackJack8/iOSAdblockList/raw/master/Regular%20Hosts.txt
https://github.com/CipherOps/MiscHostsFiles/raw/master/MiscAdTrackingHostBlock.txt
https://github.com/DK-255/Pi-hole-list-1/raw/main/Ads-Blocklist
https://github.com/DRSDavidSoft/additional-hosts/raw/master/domains/blacklist/adservers-and-trackers.txt
https://github.com/DRSDavidSoft/additional-hosts/raw/master/domains/blacklist/unwanted-iranian.txt
https://github.com/DandelionSprout/adfilt/raw/master/Alternate%20versions%20Anti-Malware%20List/AntiMalwareHosts.txt
https://github.com/DavidTai780/AdGuard-Home-Private-Rules/raw/master/hosts.txt
https://github.com/DivineEngine/Profiles/raw/master/Quantumult/Filter/Guard/Advertising.list
https://github.com/Hariharann8175/Indicators-of-Compromise-IOC-/raw/master/Ransomware%20URL's
https://github.com/JumbomanXDA/host/raw/main/hosts
https://github.com/Kees1958/W3C_annual_most_used_survey_blocklist/raw/master/EU_US%2Bmost_used_ad_and_tracking_networks
https://github.com/KurzGedanke/kurzBlock/raw/master/kurzBlock.txt
https://github.com/MajkiIT/polish-ads-filter/raw/master/polish-adblock-filters/adblock.txt
https://github.com/MitaZ/Better_Filter/raw/master/Quantumult_X/Filter.list
https://github.com/MrWaste/Ad-BlockList-2019-08-31/raw/master/Pi-Hole%20BackUps/Black%20List/All%20Server%20Black%20List
https://github.com/Neo23x0/signature-base/raw/master/iocs/c2-iocs.txt
https://github.com/Pentanium/ABClientFilters/raw/master/ko/korean.txt
https://github.com/Phentora/AdguardPersonalList/raw/master/blocklist.txt
https://github.com/ShadowWhisperer/BlockLists/raw/master/Lists/Malware
https://github.com/SlashArash/adblockfa/raw/master/adblockfa.txt
https://github.com/SukkaW/Surge/raw/master/List/domainset/reject_sukka.conf
https://github.com/Th3M3/blocklists/raw/master/tracking%26ads.list
https://github.com/TonyRL/blocklist/raw/master/hosts
https://github.com/UnbendableStraw/samsungnosnooping/raw/master/README.md
https://github.com/UnluckyLuke/BlockUnderRadarJunk/raw/master/blockunderradarjunk-list.txt
https://github.com/VernonStow/Filterlist/raw/master/Filterlist.txt
https://github.com/What-Zit-Tooya/Ad-Block/raw/main/Main-Blocklist/Ad-Block-HOSTS.txt
https://github.com/XionKzn/PiHole-Lists/raw/master/PiHole/Blocklist_HOSTS.txt
https://github.com/YanFung/Ads/raw/master/Mobile
https://github.com/Yuki2718/adblock/raw/master/adguard/tracking-plus.txt
https://github.com/Yuki2718/adblock/raw/master/japanese/jp-filters.txt
https://github.com/ZYX2019/host-block-list/raw/master/Custom.txt
https://github.com/abc45628/hosts/raw/master/hosts
https://github.com/aleclee/DNS-Blacklists/raw/master/AdHosts.txt
https://github.com/angelics/pfbng/raw/master/ads/ads-domain-list.txt
https://github.com/blocklistproject/Lists/raw/master/ransomware.txt
https://github.com/cchevy/macedonian-pi-hole-blocklist/raw/master/hosts.txt
https://github.com/craiu/mobiletrackers/raw/master/list.txt
https://github.com/curutpilek12/adguard-custom-list/raw/main/custom
https://github.com/damengzhu/banad/raw/main/jiekouAD.txt
https://github.com/deletescape/noads/raw/master/lists/add-switzerland.txt
https://github.com/doadin/Pi-Hole-Blocklist/raw/main/block.list
https://github.com/dreammjow/MyFilters/raw/main/src/filters.txt
https://github.com/durablenapkin/block/raw/master/streaming.txt
https://github.com/eEIi0A5L/adblock_filter/archive/master.zip
https://github.com/easylist-thailand/easylist-thailand/raw/master/subscription/easylist-thailand.txt
https://github.com/fandagroupofficial/hosts/raw/main/pihole/ads
https://github.com/fandagroupofficial/hosts/raw/main/pihole/log
https://github.com/fandagroupofficial/hosts/raw/main/pihole/trackers
https://github.com/faralai/Pihole-Rules/raw/master/Fara-Popups_Head
https://github.com/faralai/Pihole-Rules/raw/master/Fara-Xiaomi-info
https://github.com/farrokhi/adblock-iran/raw/master/filter.txt
https://github.com/fskreuz/blocklists/raw/dev/domains.txt
https://github.com/ftpmorph/ftprivacy/raw/master/regex-blocklists/smartphone-and-general-ads-analytics-regex-blocklist-ftprivacy.txt
https://github.com/hell-sh/Evil-Domains/raw/master/evil-domains.txt
https://github.com/hosts-file/BulgarianHostsFile/raw/master/bhf.txt
https://github.com/igorskyflyer/ad-void/raw/main/AdVoid.Core.txt
https://github.com/jackrabbit335/UsefulLinuxShellScripts/raw/master/Hosts%20%26%20sourcelist/blacklist.txt
https://github.com/jakdev121/AMS2/raw/master/pi_indo_ads.txt
https://github.com/jakejarvis/ios-trackers/raw/master/blocklist.txt
https://github.com/jasirfayas/jBlocklist/raw/master/domains.lst
https://github.com/javabean/dnsmasq-antispy/raw/master/dnsmasq.ghostery_bugs.conf
https://github.com/javabean/dnsmasq-antispy/raw/master/dnsmasq.zz-extra-servers-manual.conf
https://github.com/jdlingyu/ad-wars/raw/master/hosts
https://github.com/jlonborg/piblacklist/raw/main/blacklist.txt
https://github.com/joaopinto14/PiHole/raw/main/adverts
https://github.com/kang49/kang49regexblacklistproject/raw/main/blacklist
https://github.com/lesong/Surge/raw/main/rule/BanProgramAD.list
https://github.com/lhie1/Rules/raw/master/Auto/REJECT.conf
https://github.com/mayesidevel/PiHoleLists/raw/master/MiscBlocklist
https://github.com/meinhimmel/hosts/raw/master/hosts
https://github.com/mhhakim/pihole-blocklist/raw/master/custom-blocklist.txt
https://github.com/migueldemoura/ublock-umatrix-rulesets/raw/master/Hosts/ads-tracking
https://github.com/minoplhy/filters/raw/main/Resources/blocked.txt
https://github.com/monojp/hosts_merge/raw/master/hosts_blacklist.txt
https://github.com/mtbnunu/ad-blocklist/raw/master/kr-list.txt
https://github.com/mtxadmin/ublock/raw/master/hosts/_telemetry
https://github.com/mullvad/dns-adblock/raw/main/lists/doh/adblock/custom
https://github.com/muxcc/AdsBlockLists/raw/master/aumm.hosts
https://github.com/nimasaj/uBOPa/raw/master/uBOPa.txt
https://github.com/notracking/hosts-blocklists/raw/master/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.blacklist.txt
https://github.com/npljy/npljy.github.io/raw/main/blocks/dns.txt
https://github.com/npljy/npljy.github.io/raw/main/blocks/filter.txt
https://github.com/olegwukr/polish-privacy-filters/raw/master/adblock.txt
https://github.com/parseword/nolovia/raw/master/skel/hosts-government-malware.txt
https://github.com/parseword/nolovia/raw/master/skel/hosts-nolovia.txt
https://github.com/pathforwardit/BlockList/raw/main/DomainList
https://github.com/pirat28/IHateTracker/raw/master/iHateTracker.txt
https://github.com/sa-ki13/jmsf/raw/master/japanese_mobile_site_dns_filter.txt
https://github.com/saurane/Turkish-Blocklist/raw/master/Blocklist/domains.txt
https://github.com/scomper/surge-list/raw/master/reject.list
https://github.com/sirsunknight/QuantumultX/raw/master/Filter/Radical-Advertising
https://github.com/smed79/blacklist/raw/master/hosts.txt
https://github.com/soteria-nou/domain-list/archive/master.zip
https://github.com/stamparm/maltrail/raw/master/trails/static/suspicious/pua.txt
https://github.com/sutchan/dnsmasq_ads_filter/raw/main/dnsmasq-ads-filter-list.txt
https://github.com/svetlyobg/svet-custom-domains/raw/master/ads-domains
https://github.com/tomzuu/blacklist-named/raw/master/ad.sites.conf
https://github.com/tomzuu/blacklist-named/raw/master/phishing.sites.conf
https://github.com/tomzuu/blacklist-named/raw/master/pushing.sites.conf
https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/raw/master/filters/badware.txt
https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/raw/master/filters/filters.txt
https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/raw/master/filters/privacy.txt
https://github.com/unchartedsky/adguard-kr/raw/master/adguard-kr.txt
https://github.com/unflac/adFILTER/raw/master/filter.txt
https://github.com/vokins/ad/raw/main/ad.list
https://github.com/willianreis89/ADsBlock/raw/master/list.txt
https://github.com/wrysunny/ad_list/raw/master/adlist.txt
https://github.com/xOS/Config/raw/Her/Surge/RuleSet/Advertising.list
https://github.com/xinggsf/Adblock-Plus-Rule/raw/master/rule.txt
https://github.com/xlimit91/xlimit91-block-list/raw/master/blacklist.txt
https://github.com/xylagbx/ADBLOCK/raw/master/BLOCK/customadblockdomain.txt
https://github.com/ziozzang/adguard/raw/master/filter.txt
https://github.com/zznidar/BAR/raw/master/BAR-list
```

I'm using this command:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{if ($6~/^raw$/){$3="raw.githubusercontent.com"; for(i=0;i<=NF;++i) if (i!=6) {printf("%s%s",$i,(i==NF)?"\n":OFS)}}}' urls.txt
```

To produce this desired output:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/2RDLive/Pi-Hole/master/Blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/34730/asd/master/adaway-export
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/568475513/secret_domain/master/filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackJack8/iOSAdblockList/master/Regular%20Hosts.txt
...
```

But it yields this output:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/2RDLive/Pi-Hole/raw/master/Blacklist.txt/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/2RDLive/Pi-Hole/master/Blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/34730/asd/raw/master/adaway-export/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/34730/asd/master/adaway-export
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/568475513/secret_domain/raw/master/filter.txt/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/568475513/secret_domain/master/filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackJack8/iOSAdblockList/raw/master/Regular%20Hosts.txt/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackJack8/iOSAdblockList/master/Regular%20Hosts.txt
...
```

Why is it printing a semblance of the original URL before the correct output?

---

Here is the above code formatted legibly with `gawk -o-`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "/"
}

{
    if ($6 ~ /^raw$/) {
        $3 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
        for (i = 0; i <= NF; ++i) {
            if (i != 6) {
                printf "%s%s", $i, (i == NF) ? "\n" : OFS
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cuz you started the counter `i = 0` instead of `i = 1`. that said, after you replace `$3`, use regex to scrub it clean : from `/raw/` to `OFS`, then the line should be correct. try that

Comment: It's always that small detail! Everything works now; thanks.

Comment: if you're trying to batch grab them, this worked for most not all or it : ` echo "${a}" | mawk \47BEGIN { ORS="\42  | pv -q  >> blacklists2.txt ; \n" } { print $(!(sub("[/]raw[/]","/",$(!(NF=NF))))) }\47 FS="https://github.com/" OFS="curl -m 6000 -L -g -f \42https://raw.githubusercontent.com/"  | fish`

Comment: this worked like a charm (`@T145`) : `echo "${a}" | ` `mawk '{ __[$!++NF]++ } ` `END { ___=""; for(_ in __) { ___=(___)(",")(_) }; ` `gsub("^[,]|[/]raw","",___); printf("curl -m 6000 -L -o - --url ` `\42https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{%s}\42 | gcat - | pv -q > blacklists6.txt;\n",___) }' FS` `='https://github.com/' OFS= | dash`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Not trying to grab them, but if you're interested: https://github.com/T145/black-mirror/blob/master/scripts/v2/automated_targeting_system.bash#L37= I just found out that garbage CDNs like `rawcdn.githack.com` need to be converted too, so more cases need to be added.

Comment: If you reduce your sample input to just the minimal set that covers your use cases and add the exact expected output given that input then more people will be willing/able to help you. See [ask] and in particular [mcve]. Also, when posting code, don't cram it all into 1 line, format it legibly with indenting and line breaks to make it as easy as possible for us to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only real problem is that awk fields, arrays, and strings all start at 1, not 0, so your loop should have started at 1, not 0. As written first time through your loop `print $i` is doing `print $0`.

Having said that, I think what you want is the following with a couple of other things tidied up:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="/" }    
sub(/^raw$/,RS,$6) && sub(OFS RS,"") {
    $3 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk urls.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/2RDLive/Pi-Hole/master/Blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/34730/asd/master/adaway-export
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/568475513/secret_domain/master/filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackJack8/iOSAdblockList/master/Regular%20Hosts.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CipherOps/MiscHostsFiles/master/MiscAdTrackingHostBlock.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DK-255/Pi-hole-list-1/main/Ads-Blocklist
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DRSDavidSoft/additional-hosts/master/domains/blacklist/adservers-and-trackers.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DRSDavidSoft/additional-hosts/master/domains/blacklist/unwanted-iranian.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DandelionSprout/adfilt/master/Alternate%20versions%20Anti-Malware%20List/AntiMalwareHosts.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DavidTai780/AdGuard-Home-Private-Rules/master/hosts.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DivineEngine/Profiles/master/Quantumult/Filter/Guard/Advertising.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hariharann8175/Indicators-of-Compromise-IOC-/master/Ransomware%20URL's
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JumbomanXDA/host/main/hosts
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kees1958/W3C_annual_most_used_survey_blocklist/master/EU_US%2Bmost_used_ad_and_tracking_networks
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KurzGedanke/kurzBlock/master/kurzBlock.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MajkiIT/polish-ads-filter/master/polish-adblock-filters/adblock.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MitaZ/Better_Filter/master/Quantumult_X/Filter.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrWaste/Ad-BlockList-2019-08-31/master/Pi-Hole%20BackUps/Black%20List/All%20Server%20Black%20List
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Neo23x0/signature-base/master/iocs/c2-iocs.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pentanium/ABClientFilters/master/ko/korean.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Phentora/AdguardPersonalList/master/blocklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShadowWhisperer/BlockLists/master/Lists/Malware
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SlashArash/adblockfa/master/adblockfa.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SukkaW/Surge/master/List/domainset/reject_sukka.conf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Th3M3/blocklists/master/tracking%26ads.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TonyRL/blocklist/master/hosts
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UnbendableStraw/samsungnosnooping/master/README.md
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UnluckyLuke/BlockUnderRadarJunk/master/blockunderradarjunk-list.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VernonStow/Filterlist/master/Filterlist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/What-Zit-Tooya/Ad-Block/main/Main-Blocklist/Ad-Block-HOSTS.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XionKzn/PiHole-Lists/master/PiHole/Blocklist_HOSTS.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YanFung/Ads/master/Mobile
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yuki2718/adblock/master/adguard/tracking-plus.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yuki2718/adblock/master/japanese/jp-filters.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZYX2019/host-block-list/master/Custom.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abc45628/hosts/master/hosts
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aleclee/DNS-Blacklists/master/AdHosts.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angelics/pfbng/master/ads/ads-domain-list.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blocklistproject/Lists/master/ransomware.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cchevy/macedonian-pi-hole-blocklist/master/hosts.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/craiu/mobiletrackers/master/list.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curutpilek12/adguard-custom-list/main/custom
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damengzhu/banad/main/jiekouAD.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deletescape/noads/master/lists/add-switzerland.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doadin/Pi-Hole-Blocklist/main/block.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dreammjow/MyFilters/main/src/filters.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/durablenapkin/block/master/streaming.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/easylist-thailand/easylist-thailand/master/subscription/easylist-thailand.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fandagroupofficial/hosts/main/pihole/ads
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fandagroupofficial/hosts/main/pihole/log
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fandagroupofficial/hosts/main/pihole/trackers
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faralai/Pihole-Rules/master/Fara-Popups_Head
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faralai/Pihole-Rules/master/Fara-Xiaomi-info
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/farrokhi/adblock-iran/master/filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fskreuz/blocklists/dev/domains.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ftpmorph/ftprivacy/master/regex-blocklists/smartphone-and-general-ads-analytics-regex-blocklist-ftprivacy.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hell-sh/Evil-Domains/master/evil-domains.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hosts-file/BulgarianHostsFile/master/bhf.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorskyflyer/ad-void/main/AdVoid.Core.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackrabbit335/UsefulLinuxShellScripts/master/Hosts%20%26%20sourcelist/blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakdev121/AMS2/master/pi_indo_ads.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakejarvis/ios-trackers/master/blocklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasirfayas/jBlocklist/master/domains.lst
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javabean/dnsmasq-antispy/master/dnsmasq.ghostery_bugs.conf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javabean/dnsmasq-antispy/master/dnsmasq.zz-extra-servers-manual.conf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdlingyu/ad-wars/master/hosts
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jlonborg/piblacklist/main/blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joaopinto14/PiHole/main/adverts
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kang49/kang49regexblacklistproject/main/blacklist
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lesong/Surge/main/rule/BanProgramAD.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lhie1/Rules/master/Auto/REJECT.conf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayesidevel/PiHoleLists/master/MiscBlocklist
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meinhimmel/hosts/master/hosts
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mhhakim/pihole-blocklist/master/custom-blocklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/migueldemoura/ublock-umatrix-rulesets/master/Hosts/ads-tracking
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minoplhy/filters/main/Resources/blocked.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monojp/hosts_merge/master/hosts_blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mtbnunu/ad-blocklist/master/kr-list.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mtxadmin/ublock/master/hosts/_telemetry
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mullvad/dns-adblock/main/lists/doh/adblock/custom
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muxcc/AdsBlockLists/master/aumm.hosts
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nimasaj/uBOPa/master/uBOPa.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notracking/hosts-blocklists/master/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npljy/npljy.github.io/main/blocks/dns.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npljy/npljy.github.io/main/blocks/filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/olegwukr/polish-privacy-filters/master/adblock.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parseword/nolovia/master/skel/hosts-government-malware.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parseword/nolovia/master/skel/hosts-nolovia.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pathforwardit/BlockList/main/DomainList
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pirat28/IHateTracker/master/iHateTracker.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sa-ki13/jmsf/master/japanese_mobile_site_dns_filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saurane/Turkish-Blocklist/master/Blocklist/domains.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scomper/surge-list/master/reject.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sirsunknight/QuantumultX/master/Filter/Radical-Advertising
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smed79/blacklist/master/hosts.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stamparm/maltrail/master/trails/static/suspicious/pua.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sutchan/dnsmasq_ads_filter/main/dnsmasq-ads-filter-list.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/svetlyobg/svet-custom-domains/master/ads-domains
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomzuu/blacklist-named/master/ad.sites.conf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomzuu/blacklist-named/master/phishing.sites.conf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomzuu/blacklist-named/master/pushing.sites.conf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/master/filters/badware.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/master/filters/filters.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/master/filters/privacy.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unchartedsky/adguard-kr/master/adguard-kr.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unflac/adFILTER/master/filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vokins/ad/main/ad.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/willianreis89/ADsBlock/master/list.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrysunny/ad_list/master/adlist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xOS/Config/Her/Surge/RuleSet/Advertising.list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xinggsf/Adblock-Plus-Rule/master/rule.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xlimit91/xlimit91-block-list/master/blacklist.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xylagbx/ADBLOCK/master/BLOCK/customadblockdomain.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ziozzang/adguard/master/filter.txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zznidar/BAR/master/BAR-list
```

The only slightly tricky part in that is `sub(/^raw$/,RS,$6) && sub(OFS RS,"")` which is how you remove a mid-record field in awk - first convert the field to a string that matches RS since that can't be present in the input (we can use RS directly when it's a string like `\n` rather than a regexp) so we changed `raw` to `\n` in the 6th field which meant the record now contained `/\n/` and then removed `/\n` thereby removing the 6th field and preceding `/`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245826/discussion-on-answer-by-ed-morton-issue-converting-github-com-raw-urls-to-ra).

Comment: @Machavity thank you. I tried to do that myself when prompted but that just made a copy of the discussion instead of moving it.